How to reduce systemd's "State 'stop-sigterm' timed out" delay?
When doing a restart of my Debian machine, I got a 90s timeout from the xdg-document-portal service:
May 25 22:52:02 qaa systemd[2230]: Stopping xdg-document-portal.service - flatpak document portal service...
[...]
May 25 22:52:04 qaa systemd[1]: Started plymouth-reboot.service - Show Plymouth Reboot Screen.
May 25 22:52:04 qaa systemd[1]: plymouth-switch-root-initramfs.service - Tell Plymouth To Jump To initramfs was skipped because no trigger condition checks were met.
May 25 22:53:32 qaa systemd[2230]: xdg-document-portal.service: State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
May 25 22:53:32 qaa systemd[2230]: xdg-document-portal.service: Killing process 116031 (xdg-document-po) with signal SIGKILL.
May 25 22:53:32 qaa systemd[2230]: xdg-document-portal.service: Killing process 116037 (fusermount3) with signal SIGKILL.
May 25 22:53:32 qaa systemd[2230]: xdg-document-portal.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
May 25 22:53:32 qaa systemd[2230]: xdg-document-portal.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
May 25 22:53:32 qaa systemd[2230]: Stopped xdg-document-portal.service - flatpak document portal service.

(this is from Debian bug 1071919).
90s is too long, and I would like to reduce this delay. How?
Note: I already have a /etc/systemd/system.conf.d/stop-timeout.conf file with
[Manager]
# Note[VL]: The default 90s timeout for stopping of units is much too long!
# In general, the timeout is reached, as some unit is frozen or does not
# react. So, let us decrease it to a value that would be less annoying.
DefaultTimeoutStopSec=20s

and I had thought that to be sufficient (there is no other setting of timeout under the /etc/systemd directory). But as you can see, it is not.

tl;dr:
sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/user.conf.d
sudo mv /etc/systemd/{system,user}.conf.d/stop-timeout.conf


Here are two solutions:

Create an override for that that specific service and set TimeoutStopSec=
$ systemctl --user edit xdg-document-portal
[Service]
TimeoutStopSec=20s

Note that if you omit the --user, you'll get an error that the service was not found.  This is a good clue that you're on the wrong bus.

Override the global configuration.  @u1686_grawity is correct that this is on the user-bus, so you'll want to override the user configuration.  See man systemd-system.conf which defines DefaultTimeoutStopSec= and applies to the --system and --user buses.
[Manager]
DefaultTimeoutStopSec=20s

This needs to be added to any of the following for the system bus:

/etc/systemd/system.conf <-- For manual editing
/etc/systemd/system.conf.d/*.conf <-- Easiest to manage (IMO)
/run/systemd/system.conf.d/*.conf <-- For generated stuff
/lib/systemd/system.conf.d/*.conf <-- For package managers

But your service is on the user bus, so instead use any of these files:

~/.config/systemd/user.conf
/etc/systemd/user.conf
/etc/systemd/user.conf.d/*.conf
/run/systemd/user.conf.d/*.conf
/lib/systemd/user.conf.d/*.conf




OK, thanks for the explanations. Since I would like to reduce the timeout for everything (both system and any user), I suppose that I need a copy of the file (or a symbolic link, so that I can change the value in only one place, if need be) in both directories. For a multi-user machine, it seems surprising that a user can prevent a shutdown by putting a huge timeout value in his home directory (which has the precedence over the /etc/systemd directory).

Yep.  The copy is appropriate.  'huge' is subjective here.  When the system shuts down, it tries to stop all services (including --user services).  The service gets KillSignal=SIGTERM and that can give process a chance to notify the user that a shutdown is imminent and they need to save their work.  90s may seem long, but if your user actually needs to interact before the inevitable, 90s may even be too short.

The goal of SIGTERM here is not to interact with the user (some important services have already terminated), but to let the process do some basic cleanup. What I mean by "huge" is that a malicious user could set a timeout of several days, in which case the shutdown may take several days to complete.

system.conf.d/ only applies to the system service manager (PID 1).
Your "systemd[2230]:" is not that, it's a user service manager with its own configuration – user.conf – and its own collection of units.
